# Is ionized water safe to drink?

Tags: food-safety, water, drinks

I was searching around the internet and I found this:
http://www.thehealthleader.com/health-benefits-alkaline-water-videos/
Is this type of water safe?

Comment: I question that this is on-topic for this site. I don't think it is, but I'm not 100% sure. For now I'm going to flag it so a moderator sees it sooner rather than later. Maybe a mod can help word the question so that it's more firmly on-topic.

Comment: Hmm, the Moderator is answering questions?

Comment: They've been known to help tweak questions in order to not close them.

Comment: I'm not going to close this immediately - I think "is X safe" is generally on topic - but I also don't think this is a useful question. It's just water.

Comment: While "is X safe" is indeed allowed, I don't think it applies to this case. I wrote up a meta question, http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/, but in short, my view is that "is it safe" only defaults to "safe by food handling rules" when we are talking conventional food, not conventional home made health remedies. Everybody, please come to Meta, write about your views, and up/downvote the existing arguments so we can create a good precedent. Digile, you are invited to partake in the Meta discussion too, of course. We can reopen easily if the discussion supports it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to think that so called "alkaline water" is unsafe. There is also no good reason (that I'm aware of) to think that it's any better than any other water. I find that site a bit suspect for more than questionable health claims. They say you can make alkaline water by adding baking soda (sure), they also say that you can make alkaline water by adding lemon. *That* makes no sense at all.

Comment: And, of course, the first place your alkaline water visits in the body is your stomach where digestive acid will reverse whatever low level of alkalinity you might have added to the water.  The body regulates its own pH levels and probably isn't too impressed by the water from these machines.

Comment: This is all entirely false, but for what it's worth, the alkaline diet folks claim that foods have an health-significant effect on the pH in your body, and that this has nothing to do with whether the food itself is acidic or alkaline.